# PHP email and bcc question

Tags: php, email, bcc

I have a list of emails. I want to email all of them the same email. So I am going to use the BCC field. However, I want the TO field to show the email of whoever receives it.

How do I do this?

Comment: Are you sure this is possible? I mean without touching the smtp server code?

Comment: What's the advantage of doing it this way rather than just looping through a list of contacts and sending each of them an email TO: their address FROM: yours?  Less likely to be picked as spam as well....

Comment: Just more execution time I guess

Comment: @NinjaCat - That is far from efficient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that in one email.

Usually when people send an email to several recipients using `BCC`, they set the `to` email to their own address.